# Ajax call to webmethod gives ERROR 500

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm a beginner and I want to use ajax to load some data from database to dropdownlist when another dropdownlist selected index in changed
but I'm getting nothing but 500 error
My jquery ajax code

```
 function ddlGroups() {
        var s = $("#Content_ddlGroups").find("option:selected").prop("value");

        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //url is the path of our web method (Page name/function name)
            url: "../panels/admin/AddProject.aspx/getSubgroups",
            data: { Id: s },
            dataType: "json",
            //called on jquery ajax call success
            success: function (result) {
                $('#Content_SubGroups').empty();

                $.each(result.d, function (key, value) {
                    $("#Content_ddlGroups").append($("<option></option>").val(value.GroupID).html(value.Title));

                });

            },
            //called on jquery ajax call failure
            error: function ajaxError(result) {
                alert(result.status + ' : ' + result.statusText);
            }
        });
    };
```

and my c# code

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public static List<Group> getSubgroups(string Id)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<Group> objDept = new List<Group>();
        GroupsRepository jg = new GroupsRepository();
        //Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
        //DropDownList DDLGroups = (DropDownList)page.FindControl("DDLGroups");

        dt = jg.LoadSubGroup(Id.ToInt());
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                objDept.Add(new Group
                {
                    GroupID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][0]),
                    Title = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString(),
                });
            }
        }
        return objDept;
    }
```

What is the problem??

Comment: 500 means that an Exception was thrown. You could either *debug your code* or at least add a `try-catch`.

Comment: To add to Camilo's comment, the error is happening in 'getSubgroups' code, so that's where you need to add your try catch to see the actual error.

Comment: @Sparrow how can I see the error ?  I added try catch in my code but i dont  know how to show the erorr

Comment: Well...You can add some statements in the catch block to log (write) the exception's message and/or the stack trace somewhere (usually applications have a file or table for these logs). You could also put a break point in your service and manually debug. Yo can even use the Debug class (in  System.Diagnostics namespace) to see which line is throwing the exception and what the exception is

Comment: Since you are a beginner, I think the easiest option is using the Diagnostics

Comment: see this link for more help: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815788/how-to-trace-and-debug-in-visual-c

Comment: can you confirm the URL you passed in $.ajax method is correct. please try complete http:// url to make sure no issue with URL.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery is not the problem here. The 500 error is thrown by the server, so you should review the log of your c# code to find out the details about it and be able to narrow the causes.

Answer (score 0):

In your AJAX Call actually 500 error caused beacuse you have passed 
Id:s instead of Id having some digits. Ex. Id : 5.

I see your code if you passed string as a id so in your server side method 
you are trying to convert that string to int.That actually causes the 500 error.

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public static List<Group> getSubgroups(string Id)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<Group> objDept = new List<Group>();
        GroupsRepository jg = new GroupsRepository();
        //Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
        //DropDownList DDLGroups = (DropDownList)page.FindControl("DDLGroups");

        dt = jg.LoadSubGroup(Id.ToInt()); // Here You have convert string to Int that's why you got 500 Error.

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                objDept.Add(new Group
                {
                    GroupID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][0]),
                    Title = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString(),
                });
            }
        }
        return objDept;
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting this error ::Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'Id'

Comment: Hi.Javad. use Json.stringify. for ex. data : JSON.stringify({Id:5}). this helps. other way is data:"{'Id':'" +"s"+ "'}"